# document.getElementbyId: Object required

Tags: vbscript

I have some code on a classic ASP page that is attempting to get the `innerHTML` of a `<div>` element.

```
    Dim oElm 
    Set oElm = document.getElementById("screenDiv")

    if oElm Is Nothing then
        '''
    else
        document.getElementById("screenDiv").innerHTML = ""
    end if
```

I've tried the above but I'm getting the Object Required error.

What do I need to do to get around this error?

Comment: yes it is client side.  I don't have a choice at this point in time.  It is a legacy app that is partially javascript and partially vbscript.

Comment: if this is clientside code then it has nothing to do with ASP-classic which is all serverside.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **NOTE: client side VBScript is outdated, deprecated, and doesn't work in any modern browser including newer versions of IE.**

This means the code is located before the element, so when it executes, such 
element does not exist.

To solve this, have the code execute in the `onload` event:

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
Set window.onload = GetRef("WindowLoad")
Function WindowLoad
    Dim oElm 
    Set oElm = document.getElementById("screenDiv")
    if oElm Is Nothing then
        MsgBox("element does not exist")
    else
        oElm.innerHTML = ""
    end if
End Function
</script>
```

Credit for the correct way goes to [Korikulum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304039/document-getelementbyid-object-required/8310051#comment16861557_8310051), and the official documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974564.aspx).

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/aGq7J/2/). (IE only)

Comment: The reason `window.onload` isn't working is because you're using it incorrectly. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974564.aspx) it should be used like this: `Set window.onload = GetRef("WindowLoad")`

Comment: @Korikulum awesome, thanks! Can't believe I failed to find it myself. :/

Comment: `If inStr(IE.Document.body.innerhtml, "Please sign in.") Then  'do something        Else
  MsgBox("element does not exist")
    End If` would also work. I have not been able to replicate @ShadowWizard 's method